# How to download multiple BLOBs(Images/Files) at once in Oracle Apex 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I was wondering if there is a way to download all the blob content from a table at once on the application side (via a button click ideally).

I could get it to download BLOB files/images on a record by record basis both on the interactive report and on the form using different approaches. But getting more than one at a time seems to be a rather tricky for me.

I am using 
Oracle Apex 5.0.4. and 
Oracle Database:12c.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A few links I went through:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/up_dn_files.htm#CHDECDAJ

http://joelkallman.blogspot.be/2014/03/yet-another-post-how-to-link-to.html

Answer (score 2):

No you can't download multiple files when clicking on a "download Button".

What you can do is build a zip file (in the server) with your selection of BLOBS and that is the one to download.

UTL_COMPRESS is the Oracle Package to do that.
An example on how to do it is here: [UTL_COMPRESS, gzip and zip](https://technology.amis.nl/2010/03/13/utl_compress-gzip-and-zlib/)

Another one is the AS_ZIP: [AS_ZIP](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27830124/zip-and-unzip-in-PLSQL.html)

and ZIP_UTIL_PKG: [ZIP_UTIL_PKG](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils/blob/master/ora/zip_util_pkg.pkb)

Comment: And another package built in to apex: apex_zip.  Then send it to the users' browser with  oos_util_web.download_file()

Answer (score 1):

I have recently published a solution for that using 4 steps:

1. Create a button to submit the page;
2. Create a page process that creates the blob of a zip file, using apex_zip API and stores it in a collection (using apex_collection);
3. Create a branch to the same page, calling an application_process=something;
4. Create an Ajax Callback called 'something' that prompts the user to open or download the zip file using WPG_DOCLOAD.download_file.

Take a look and let me know: https://apexcornies.wordpress.com/2020/04/04/create-a-download-zip-button-in-oracle-apex/

Cheers,
Pedro